# Displaying symbol after value in TextField

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am currently using the following code for Material-UI TextField

```
<TextField
  id="submissionMark"
  name="submissionMark"
  type="number"
  label="Submission Mark"
  className={classes.textField}
  value={Math.round(this.state.mark)}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  helperText={this.state.errors.mark}
  error={this.state.errors.mark ? true : false}
  fullWidth
/>
```

The value in the text field is a number but I am trying to show a `%` after the number  without appending the `%` to the state.

I tried searching through the APIs and online for a solution but could not find anything.

Example:
User inputs `55` and the text field displays `55%`

Is such thing possible to be displayed?

Comment: Am not sure you can do this without the state. Is it that you do not want to use the state completely?

Comment: See my related answer for one approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54702150/add-suffix-follow-by-user-input-material-ui-textfield/54702468#54702468

Answer (score 1):

Just append `%` at the end of `value` prop. This way you won't have to store the symbol in state.

```
<TextField
  id="submissionMark"
  name="submissionMark"
  type="number"
  label="Submission Mark"
  className={classes.textField}
  value={`${Math.round(this.state.mark)}%`}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  helperText={this.state.errors.mark}
  error={this.state.errors.mark ? true : false}
  fullWidth
/>
```